# tehcnic not working ubuntu 17.04

Tags: 17.04

After upgrading ubuntu to 17.04 my technic launcher stopped working. When
clicking on I get the following error message:

> The file /home/kael/Desktop/TechnicLauncher.jar' is not marked as
>   executable.  If this was downloaded or copied from an untrusted
>   source, it may be dangerous to run.  For more details, read about the
>   executable bit.

I tried to reinstall but it didn't work, is there a fix to this?

Answer (score 0):

The problem and therefore the solution are clearly stated in the error report: `TechnicLauncher.jar' is not marked as executable.`

To fix this you can either right-click the file, chose properties, and mark it as executable in the Tab regarding the file permissions.

Or you can run `chmod u+x ~/Desktop/TechnicLauncher.jar` inside a Terminal.